# installing Wordpress on live Windows server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis, webmatrix

We have a web server which already has some asp.net web applications running on it. Recently management has decided to convert our website to WordPress so I need to install Wordpress on Windows web server.

I am not a WordPress guy, can you please guide me what things I will need to install and what would be easiest way for  that. I m wondering do I need to install MYSQL, Php, Apachi along with Wordpress ? How you see using MS Web Matrix to do word press installation on server which already has some live applications.

I highly appreciate your time, help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try [WampServer](http://wampserver.com)

It is an open source development stack for Windows that includes Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

Comment: IIS is already installed. Regardless of how good/bad you think one or the other is ... installing two web servers in the one box is a bad idea. Port sharing, anyone?

Comment: What about Wordpress ? Is it prerequsite to install WampServer for Wordpress ? and how about MS Web Matrix ?

Comment: @ ta.speot.is, cant I run wordpress with IIS ?

Comment: You can run Wordpress under IIS but don't be surprised if you run into incompatability problems. Wordpress is geared toward a Linux/Apache environment, not IIS. You can install it using WebMatrix on IIS - http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress/